# serializing data with google charts api

Tags: php, api, google-visualization

I have the following google chart code that im working with as an example:

```
Type: Line
Dimensions: 270x150
283,285,295,204,340,#41C0E4
64,120,130,170,175,180,#3962C2
1,2,5,12,28,34,#005E91
Bottom Label: test
```

The following is the URL which generates the image below

https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=270x150&cht=lc&chtt=&chd=s:zz1l9,LWXffg,AABCFG&chco=41C0E4,3962C2,005E91&chxl=0:|test|&chxt=x

[image]

My question is that i dont see the actual data in the url, but i see this

```
chd=s:zz1l9,LWXffg,AABCFG
```

That looks like serialized data, but im wondering how exactly that works, or how to encode/decode that to make the input of chart data dynamic via php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the simple encoding format.

See about it [here in the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#simple).